# Adding Swift To Objective-C Projects Compile error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

> Hi Im getting the following error on my class definition
>
> Im getting the following error on my class definition
>
> expected '{' in class
>
> My define Module = Yes bridge.h is setup
>
> embedded content contains swift = Yes
>
> Code is as follows

```
    class HeaderFooterView : UIView {



    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
        self.autoresizesSubviews = true
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
        self.autoresizesSubviews = true
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

add @objc before class

```
@objc class HeaderFooterView : UIView {
```